# recursion in python for delivering something by only going back and forth

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

I got a task I cannot solve: A *recursive* function in python shell be written that returns how many possible ways exist for an object to reach an ending point with a certain amount of steps and a given starting point, whereat all those values are given as integers. The object can move foreward and backward. For instance start: 1, stop: 3, steps: 4 -> possible ways = 4

So far I got something like this:

```
def wiggle(start, end, moves):
    if start == end and moves == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return wiggle(start-1, end, moves-1) + wiggle(start+1, end, moves-1)

print wiggle(1,3,4)
```

The recursion is continuing to infinity and I'm not sure about the *else*.
I feel like there are only slight changes necessary, but I don't know how to accomplish them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you need an additional case for when `moves` is zero but you haven't reached the end point. Otherwise you may end up descending into calls where `moves` is negative.

```
def wiggle(start, end, moves):
    if start == end and moves == 0:
        return 1
    elif start != end and moves == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return wiggle(start-1, end, moves-1) + wiggle(start+1, end, moves-1)

print wiggle(1,3,4)
```

Alternate formatting, same logic:

```
def wiggle(start, end, moves):
    if moves == 0:
        return 1 if start == end else 0
    else:
        return wiggle(start-1, end, moves-1) + wiggle(start+1, end, moves-1)

print wiggle(1,3,4)
```

Comment: wow, thank your very much, Kevin! That was quick and perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing a condition for exiting the function when no moves are left.

For instance:

```
def wiggle(start, end, moves):
    if start == end and moves == 0:
        return 1
    elif moves == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return wiggle(start-1, end, moves-1) + wiggle(start+1, end, moves-1)
```